# Wordpress change comment error message

Tags: wordpress, comments

is there any way to change the default wordpress message:

Error: please fill the required fields (name, email)

from "wp-comments-post.php" file? Obviously without changing it directly in this wordpress file.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to change the message in english or in another language? Because this message is processed through gettext, so you might be able to translate it.

Comment: The message, should be "Please fill in the required field."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to check if any of your comment form `input` elements are empty, and if they are, display an error message and prevent the form from submitting.

Using `#email` and `#author` as example `input` elements, you could do something like this (not tested):

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#author").val()) === "") {
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
        return false;
    }
});
```

You could take it a step further by showing an element within the comment form instead of a browser alert pop up.

Using a hidden element in your comments form markup:

```
<div class="error-message" style="display:none">custom error message here</div>
```

Then show that message when the fields are empty like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#author").val()) === "") {
         $(".error-message").fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
});
```